# Is there a something similar to a With statement that can be used with arrays?

Tags: excel, vba

The `if` statement looks at criteria to determine which worksheet to use for the following section. It then sets the sheet name accordingly.

I am unsure what the best way is to put an array in either statement instead of how it currently is with worksheet ranges, since I don't believe I can use the `WITH` statement to hold the array name that is referenced.

Any help is appreciated.  thank you

```vb
'sets which date range sheet to use
If spbe30array(i, 22) >= orders Then
    Set spbe = spbe30
Else
    Set spbe = spbe60
End If
            
'the section below is using a sheet name that is determined from the if statement above
i = i + 1
With spbe
    Do While LCase(.Range("b" & i).Value) = "placement"
        If LCase(.Range("aa" & i).Value) = "product" Then
            PPclicks = .Range("t" & i).Value
        ElseIf LCase(.Range("aa" & i).Value) = "rest" Then
            ROSclicks = .Range("t" & i).Value
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: What do you mean "convert everything to an array,"? What exactly do you want to  re-code using arrays? The code above already uses arrays in `spbe30array`, so what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am currently running the entire script referring to worksheet ranges. I want to speed it up by converting everything from worksheet ranges to using arrays instead...

Comment: So instead of `.Range("t" & i).Value` you would enter `t_array(i,1)` instead? In that case, there is no longer a need for `With` statements. In fact, there is never a **need** for `With` statements it is just a convenience so you don't have to fully qualify workbook/sheet/range every time.

Comment: this is my problem - the first IF statement look at criteria to determine which array to work off of. It then sets an array name variable that is referenced throughout the rest of the script. I just don't know how to say:   ArrayToUse=Array1     ArraytoUse(1,2)

Comment: You can pull values into the arrays _after_ the if statement. So there is only one set of arrays to work of, wither from `spbe30` or `spbe60`

Comment: The array i would be using after the IF statement would change potentially thousands of times throughout the script running. It seems like constantly pulling the values from Array1 or Array2 into ArraytoUse would be very slow.

Comment: If this is the case, there isn't enough information on the question to effectively answer. You are asking about something specific and then it might be slow in the grand scheme of things. Try it first and then see if further optimization can be done.

If you want to keep multiple sets of arrays in memory, then use _an array of arrays_ such as `b_all = Array( b_array1, b_array2, ..)` and then access it with `b_all(0)(i,1)` or `b_all(1)(i,1)`

Comment: You cannot directly assign an array reference to a variable, as it copies the array. You can however pass an array to a subroutine by reference without copying. So have a `Private Sub FiddleWithArray(ByRef arr As Variant)`, move your array-manipulating logic in there, and pass it different arrays as in, `If (condition) Then FiddleWithArray a1 Else FiddleWithArray a2`.

Comment: `PPclicks = .Range("t" & i).Value` doesn't make much sense to me. Shouldn't it rather be `.Range("t" & i).Value = PPclicks`? Please, elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want.

You can pull the values from the worksheet after the selection is made using the `If` statement.

```
    'sets which date range sheet to use
    If spbe30array(i, 22) >= orders Then
        Set spbe = spbe30
    Else
        Set spbe = spbe60
    End If
       
    Dim b_array() As Variant, aa_array() As Variant, t_array() As Variant
    Dim n_rows As Long
    
    n_rows = 100 'Figure Out how many rows to process
    
    ' Start from row#2 skipping headers
    b_array = spbe.Range("b2").Resize(n_rows, 1).Value
    aa_array = spbe.Range("aa2").Resize(n_rows, 1).Value
    t_array = spbe.Range("t2").Resize(n_rows, 1).Value

             
    'the section below is using a sheet name that is determined from the if statement above
    i = i + 1
    Do While LCase(b_array(i, 1)) = "placement"
        If LCase(aa_array(i, 1)) = "product" Then
            PPclicks = t_array(i, 1)
        ElseIf LCase(aa_array(i, 1)) = "rest" Then
            ROSclicks = t_array(i, 1)
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
```

---

Based on further comments, I recommend using an array of arrays

```
Dim b_array() as Variant, aa_array() as Variant, t_array() as Variant

b_array = Array( _
    spbe30.Range("b2").Resize(n_rows, 1).Value, 
    spbe60.Range("b2").Resize(n_rows, 1).Value )

aa_array = Array( _
    spbe30.Range("aa2").Resize(n_rows, 1).Value, 
    spbe60.Range("aa2").Resize(n_rows, 1).Value )

t_array = Array( _
    spbe30.Range("t2").Resize(n_rows, 1).Value, 
    spbe60.Range("t2").Resize(n_rows, 1).Value )
```

and then pick the one to use

```
    Dim index as Long
    If spbe30array(i,22) >= orders Then
        index = 0
    Else
        index = 1
    End If

    Do While LCase(b_array(index)(i, 1)) = "placement"
        If LCase(aa_array(index)(i, 1)) = "product" Then
            PPclicks = t_array(index)(i, 1)
        ElseIf LCase(aa_array(index)(i, 1)) = "rest" Then
            ROSclicks = t_array(index)(i, 1)
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
```

Comment: ultimately, what I want is to say: If criteria 1 then X=array1, if criteria 2 then X=array2. Once this is determined, then reference the array as X(1,1)

Comment: I think there is a bug in Excel where `Array( Range().Value )` will not work. you need to pull the values into work arrays first, and them combine them with the `Array()` function. I just wanted to present the gist of it here.

Answer (score 0):

### Jagged Array, ByRef/ByVal

- You could write the values of the ranges to arrays and copy the arrays to another array (jagged array or array of arrays). Then, using the jagged array's index in an `IIf` function, you could easily decide which array to use.
- To not clutter your code, you could additionally create another procedure to do the job from your `With` statement.
- The `Do Loop` still doesn't make sense to me. Maybe you're missing an `Exit Do` or two.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Snippet()
    
'    ' Your initial variables (to be able to compile my code)
'    Dim spbe30array As Variant, PPClicks As Variant, ROSclicks As Variant
'    Dim orders As Double
'    Dim i As Long
    
    Dim spbeData As Variant: ReDim spbeData(1 To 2)
    spbeData(1) = spbe30.Value
    spbeData(2) = spbe60.Value
 
    Dim Index As Long: Index = IIf(spbe30array(i, 22) >= orders, 1, 2)
    
    i = i + 1
    UpdateClicks spbeData, Index, i, PPClicks, ROSclicks
    ' 'i', 'PPClicks', 'ROSclicks' have been passed 'By Ref',
    ' so they are possibly modified.
    ' If 'i' is not relevant for the continuation, pass it 'ByVal'.
    ' 'spbeData' and 'Index' remain unchanged.
    
End Sub

Sub UpdateClicks( _
        ByVal spbeData As Variant, _
        ByVal Index As Long, _
        ByRef i As Long, _
        ByRef PPClicks As Variant, _
        ByRef ROSclicks As Variant)
        
    Do While LCase(spbeData(Index)(i, 2)) = "placement"
        If LCase(spbeData(Index)(i, 27)) = "product" Then
            PPClicks = spbeData(Index)(i, 20)
        ElseIf LCase(spbeData(Index)(i, 27)) = "rest" Then
            ROSclicks = spbeData(Index)(i, 20)
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```